# understanding size command for data bss segment in C

Tags: c, windows, gcc, memory-layout

I'm getting unexpected output from `size` command.

Afaik initialized global and static variables stored in `data` segment and uninitialized and initialized to 0 global/static variables stored in `bss` segment.

`printf("%d",sizeof(int));` gives `int` size 4. However, `bss` and `data` segment is not increasing accordingly to 4.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    return 0;
}

C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin>size memory-layout.exe
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  10044    2292    2512   14848    3a00 memory-layout.exe

#include <stdio.h>
int g; //uninitialised global variable so, stored in bss segment
int main()
{
    return 0;
}

C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin>size memory-layout.exe
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  10044    2292    2528   14864    3a10 memory-layout.exe
```

why `bss` increased by 16 (2528 - 2512) instead of 4? (in above code)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int g=0; //initialised to 0 so, stored in bss segment
int main()
{
    return 0;
}

C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin>size memory-layout.exe
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  10044    2292    2512   14848    3a00 memory-layout.exe
```

there is no increment in `bss` in spite of using global variable. why's that?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{   static int g; //should be on bss segment
    return 0;
}

C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin>size memory-layout.ex
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  10044    2292    2512   14848    3a00 memory-layout.exe
```

no increment in `bss` segment in spite of using static variable, why?

and I have one more question, what `dec` represents here?

Comment: Use the [`od`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html) or [`nm`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html) commands to list object/executable files, their sections and their sections.

Comment: @a3f what's the significance

Comment: @JoachimPileborg no od command found in MinGW

Comment: case `int g = 0;`  - as initialized global is not stored in BSS.

Comment: @AntoJurković read here about this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment

Comment: Didn't know about that. I was checking Peter van der Linden book "Expert C Programming". Anyway, [BSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) says " An implementation may also assign statically-allocated variables and constants initialized with a value consisting solely of zero-valued bits to the BSS section." So it seems it is implementation dependent.

Comment: Seems to me `dec = text + data + bss`. And` hex` is same as `dec` but ...in hex. ;)

Comment: Look in the linker map to see where these variables *actually* went.  It looks like your linker is increasing the sizes of sections in 16-byte increments instead of 4-byte increments. You could experiment with this by doing `int a; int b; int c; int d; int e;` in stages and noting when it increases in size.  The `int g = 0;` case seems to suggest it is going into `.data` and didn't increase because there was already room as we just saw.

Comment: Also bear in mind that variables may be optimized out if the compiler realizes they are unused; this could be happening in cases 2 and 3.

Comment: It is implementation-dependent whether BSS and DATA even exist of course. I have used systems where `int g = 0;` goes in DATA and some where it goes in BSS.  Of course the sensible thing would be for it to go in BSS , IDK whether the compiler vendor just couldn't be bothered or what. In one of my code bases I ended up having to write `int g ZERO_INITIALIZED;` where that is a macro that expands to either blank or to `= { 0 }` depending on which compiler/platform is in use

Comment: case 1 : uninitialized global : value is in BSS. Linker is allocating space in BSS at 16 byte boundaries. Hence, BSS size is increased by 16.
case 2 : initialized to zero: compiler is not considering this as a case of default initialization and puts it in Data segment along with other initialized global variables. Hence, no increase in BSS
case 3: static variable inside a function. Compiler knows you are not using this variable. No space allocated in BSS. In previous cases, since these were global variable, compiler cannot optimize it out. 
dec : total size = text + bss + data in decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to consider is memory alignment. Variables and sections can be padded to make them sit on address boundaries. In the second example you are seeing an increase of 16 from the first, which suggests padding for 16-byte boundaries (2512 / 16 = 157, 2528 / 16 = 158). This is entirely implementation dependent.

As far as C is concerned, the second example differs from the third because the compiler cannot know if `int g` is a definition or just a declaration for an integer defined in another file (where it could be any value). It leaves a reference for the linker to deal with instead, which may lead to differences in padding.

In the third example, `g` is explicitly defined and set to 0, so the compiler knows to put this in the BSS section.

It's possible to demonstrate this with the generated assembly from my system:

with `int g` (no BSS section is defined in this case)

```
.comm   g,4,4
```

This is a instruction for the linker to deal with the symbol, as the compiler cannot fully determine what to do with it.

with `int g = 0`

```
    .bss
    .align 4
    .type   g, @object
    .size   g, 4
g:
    .zero   4
```

Here the compiler knows exactly what to do and so defines a BSS section for the symbol.

In my case, the linker resolves these identically. Both are placed in the BSS section at the same address, and so there is no difference in BSS size. You can examine the layout with a utility like `nm`.

```
nm -n file2 file3 | grep g$

000000000060103c B g
000000000060103c B g
```

i.e. on this system `g` is at the same address. Alternatively, with a debugger:

```
(gdb) info symbol 0x60103c
g in section .bss of /tmp/file2
```

Note also that in the final example the variable can be optimised out, since it has internal linkage.

As for `dec`, it is simply the sum of the sections in decimal.

Answer (score 1):

This is from gcc on linux:

```
No Variable
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    915     248       8    1171     493 none.out
Uninitialized Global
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    915     248      12    1175     497 u_g.out
Initialized Global to 123
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    915     252       8    1175     497 i_g.out
Initialized Local to 124
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    915     252       8    1175     497 i_l.out
Initialized Global to 0
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    915     248      12    1175     497 i_g_0.out
Initialized Local to 0
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    915     248      12    1175     497 i_l_0.out
```

This is from mingw64 on Windows:

```
No Variable
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   3173    1976     448    5597    15dd none.out
Uninitialized Global
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   3173    1976     464    5613    15ed u_g.out
Initialized Global to 123
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   3173    1976     448    5597    15dd i_g.out
Initialized Local to 124
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   3173    1976     448    5597    15dd i_l.out
Initialized Global to 0
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   3173    1976     480    5629    15fd i_g_0.out
Initialized Local to 0
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   3173    1976     480    5629    15fd i_l_0.out
```

So although I don't have a final answer to the question (wouldn't fit in a comment), results make me suspect the executable file format of Windows and/or MinGW (i.e. not gcc).

Answer (score 0):

BSS only contains static and global values which are not explicitly initialized.  Even though you are explicitly initializing it to the same value to which it would be initialized if it were not initialized explicitly, the fact of explicit initialization means it doesn't belong in bss.

Comment: This is incorrect. Data initialised to zero may be in the BSS section.

Comment: @teppic, even if it were true that it **may** be in the BSS segment, the fact that it **is** explicitly initialized (even to 0) means that it **need not** be  in the BSS segment.  The only case in which it can be said that it **must** be in BSS is when it is **not** explicitly initialized global static.

Comment: It's up to the implementation, it doesn't have to use BSS for anything.

Comment: How about this: if it has BSS and it stores uninitilized data in BSS (which what BSS is intended for), then storing data initialized to 0 in BSS is an optional optimization.

Comment: The problem is it's all optional, there's no standard and it's defined by the implementation (both hardware and compiler). BSS is more about storing data that should be zero, without having to allocate the space in the binary.